# About applying formulas to a CSV file in shell script

Tags: shell, csv, sh, formula

I'm new in shell script and want to learn how to create an easy script to do the following:

1. Create n columns in my CSV file
2. Apply formulas that use the other columns to create values in these new columns for each line
3. Write columns in current file (I don't want to create a new file for output)

Example of what I have:

```
X,Y,Z,LAT,LONG
-981,545,3643
-979,544,3644
```

Example of what I want:

```
X,Y,Z,LAT,LONG
-981,545,3643,$X*$X,$LAT*$Y
-979,544,3644,$X*$X,$LAT*$Y
```

I have a very large file, so I'm looking for something simple. I'm sorry for my English and thank you for your help!!

Edit: I want to calculate the last column with the new column I just created, but with only one step.

Answer (score 2):

**awk** approach:

```
awk 'BEGIN {
    FS=",";
    OFS=",";
}
{
    if (NR == 1) {
        print $0, "X*X", "LAT*Y"
    } else {
        print $0, $1*$1, $2*$4;
    }
}' data.csv > tmp_data.csv

mv tmp_data.csv data.csv
```

Output:

```
X,Y,Z,LAT,LONG,X*X,LAT*Y
-981,545,3643,962361,0
-979,544,3644,958441,0
```

Comment: When I do this, the value of the last column is zero. It doesn't work.

Comment: @IsabelaMartins Your input only has three columns, as the `LAT` is always 0, so the result is zero.

Comment: That's the point! I want to create the LAT column and the LONG column. Is there a way that I can do this in a one shot way? Or do I have to write separate blocks in my script to create one column at a time?

Comment: @IsabelaMartins what's your rule to make LAT and LONG, add code to the script above will solve your problem.